# Back vs. Menu Control

Tags: user-behavior, menu

We have a lot of elderly users for our app who are always looking for a back button.

However, we need to integrate a menu and the right top spot in the nav bar is occupied.

What do you think of putting in the middle of the navbar (instead of a titel)?

What is your experience with users looking for a missing back button?

Comment: Could you please post a mockup or a screenshot of your current layout?

Comment: If it's an iOS or Android native app, the "back" (or "Up" in the case of Android) button should go on the left. Why are you only listing the right and center as options?

Comment: Is this part of a task or workflow? If so then the back button should be placed near other navigation controls rather than where it is convenient. Also, if the workflow is not complex, they might just look for the menu if the back button is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DallonF. I read from your description (you mentioned "app") that you are targeting touch devices (mobile, tablet)? So first to go would be to keep consistency with the running OS on the device. Think of the native interactions (e.g. swipe on tables to move a screen back on iOS) too. So the user has only the effort to learn navigation and interactions once. If you invent a new way for navigation, you add some effort. So if you HAVE TO make a new way of navigation, keep close the native one.

If you need "munition" for discussions, refer to current browsers. Safari, Chrome, Firefox have their nav buttons on the upper left corner.

hope this helps